# Offset between the armor stand location and the armor stand head location

Tags: minecraft

I cannot for the life of me find the offset between the head location and the location of an armor stand.

What I am trying to achieve is: Teleport the armor stand based on the it's head's location (So that it shows the item in the middle of the block.)

I don't think getHeight or eye is at the correct height but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you show your code ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: I'm stuck at what the offset between the head location and the normal location.

Comment: Yes but did you tried something ? With `.5` it's not enough ?

Comment: Well It's over 1, and it's not a 1.5 offset. I'm talking about getting the head on the armor stand in the middle of the Y axis of the block

Answer (score 0):

Acording to https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Armor_Stand, the height of an armor stand is 1.975 blocks

```
Normal:

Width: 0.5 Blocks

Height: 1.975 Blocks

Small:

Width: 0.25 Blocks

Height: 0.9875 Blocks
```

Comment: While this is true, this is not relevant. As I'm looking for the Distance between the **head** location, and the normal location